# Public read-only access to a private var in Scala

Tags: scala, constructor

**Preamble**: I'm teaching a course in object-functional programming using Scala and one of the things we do is to take sample problems and compare how they might be implemented using object-functional programming and using state-based, object-oriented programming, which is the background most of the students have.

So I want to implement a simple class in Scala that has a `private var` with a `public` accessor method (a very common idiom in state-based, object-oriented programming). Looking at Alvin Alexander's "Scala Cookbook" the recommended code to do this is pretty ghastly:

```
class Person(private var _age: Int): 
  def incrAge() = _age += 1
  def age = _age
```

I say "ghastly" because I'm having to invent two names that essentially represent the `age` field, one used in the constructor and another used in the class interface. I'm curious if people more familiar with Scala would know of a simpler syntax that would avoid this?

**EDIT**: It seems clear to me now that Scala combines the `val`/`var` declaration with the given visibility (`public`/`private`), so for a `var` either both accessor&mutator are `public` or both are `private`. Depending on perspective, you might find this inflexible, or feel it rightly punishes you for using `var` .

Comment: _"Is there any better of doing this?"_ other than not using `vars` and rather using an immutable case class, no I can't think of a _"better way"_. Mainly because I don't understand what is wrong with this?

Comment: Having to create two names to manage a single field is ugly. The `age` accessor gives the impression the field is called `age` but the client must remember to use `_age` if using pass-by-name in the constructor. This would not happen in e.g. Java or Ruby. I can't use a case class as I want proper objects with identity.

Comment: _"This would not happen in e.g. Java or Ruby."_ of course it would _(at least in **Java**)_, actually worse, you would need the `age` property, the `getAge` method, and the `name` parameter to the constructor and you would need to do `this.age = age` to achieve the same behavior, you can use `age` in **Scala** just name the getter `getAge`. - _"I can't use a case class as I want proper objects with identity"_ no idea what proper object means buy you can always use `eq` if you need to use reference equality but that is usually a bad idea or unnecessary.

Comment: Exactly. In Java, for all its flaws, the field `age` can have the same name as the constructor argument used to initialise it. I find it odd that Scala doesn't handle this common case more elegantly. BTW, this explains object identity: https://www.scala-exercises.org/scala_tutorial/classes_vs_case_classes.

Comment: I know what is object identity, I am telling you that if you want it you can always get it by using `eq` instead of `==` but also pointing out that is a bad idea in most situations. - _"I find it odd that Scala doesn't handle this common case more elegantly"_ is not common at all, both because is not common to have mutability and even less common to have a mutable field whose getter is public but not its setter; in any case, the conceptual reason why you can't do that in **Scala** is because constructor arguments are also fields of the class _(i.w. it is doing the same as **Java**)_

Comment: Anyways, you can get what you want with a little bit more of boilerplate: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/qmBOURkQQuaEmmgPPhdOtg/1

Comment: "it is not common to have mutability and even less common to have a mutable field whose getter is public" It's extremely common in OOP, a paradigm that Scala supports.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a better way of doing it is not using `var`

```
class Person(val age: Int) {
   def incrAge = new Person(age+1)
}
```

If you are going to write idiomatic scala code, you should start with pretending that certain parts of it simply do not exist: mostly `var`s, `null`s and `return`s, but also mutable structures or collections, arrays, and certain methods like `.get` on a `Try` or an `Option`, or the `Await` object. Oh, and also `isInstanceOf` and `asInstance`.

You may ask "why do these things exist if they are not supposed to be used?". Well, because *sometimes*, in a very few very specific cases they are actually useful for achieving a very limited very specific purpose. But that would be probably fewer than 0.1% of the cases you will come across in your career, unless you are involved in some hard core low level library development (in which case, you would not be posting questions like this here).

So, until you acquire enough command of the language to be able to definitively distinguish those 0.1% of the cases from the other 99.9%, you are much better off simply ignoring those language features, and pretending they do not exist (if you can't figure out how to achieve a certain task without using one of those, post a question here, and people will gladly help you).

You said "Having to create two names to manage a single field is ugly." Indeed. But you know what's uglier? Using vars.

(Btw, the way you typically do this in java is `getAge` and `setAge` – still two names. The ugliness is rooted in allowing the value labeled with the given name to be different at different points of program execution, not in how specifically the semantics of mutation looks like).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've been full-time software professional for 30+ years, PhD etc., so not seeking newbie advice. Scala purports to support OOP and I'm puzzled that expressing a simple OOP idiom requires creating an artificial name and assumed I must be missing something. It seems not. The answer may be what lies behind your answer which is that Scala just does not support OOP idioms very well, which simply surprises me.

Comment: I was hoping you'd at least try to answer my question appropriately, rather than making inane remarks like "OOP is not synonymous with Java."

Comment: @ComDubh trust me, your degrees and experience in. other areas notwithstanding, "avoid vars" is the most appropriate answer to your question that you can ever to get. Also, if you are going to be writing comments seriously suggesting that OOP implies mutability, then be ready to get answers among which my "non synonymous to Java" remark is one of the most constructive. :)